# Proper resolution for large scale printing

Tags: print-design

I'm not savvy at all when it comes to any of this.  We need a photo of our dog that will be blown up to go on a van wrap. My photographer has a camera with 24 mega pixels which is a 4000x6000 resolution.  Will this be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine. Remember large format graphics such a billboard, tradeshow panels, ect... can be printed at a much lower dpi (85-120dpi +/-) which can help enlarge your image dimensions. It wont be as sharp as an image in print, but usually viewers will be looking from a distance.